# Improving answers that are wrong or ambiguous

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement, wrong-answers

On a few occasions now I have noticed many basic questions being asked which could be solved with a quick Google search or read of the official documentation.  In any event there are people with fair rep who answer the question but give either misleading or down-right wrong information.

[Example of this kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076237/how-to-pass-id-in-laravel-url-parameter/36076312?noredirect=1#36076312)

So, I attempted to edit the answer which was quickly rejected by the answerer.  I do not wish to create another answer that's identical to theirs without the wrongful information.

I attempted to persuede the author to accept my changes and as you can see a length unhelpful exchange of comments happened.  So I tidied them up and started a chat - it was not accepted by the author.

So what are my options at this point?  Yes the answer does solve the problem, but then the answer also has misleading and wrong information which needs improvement, I feel powerless.

Comment: You can provide an answer yourself, and you can add a comment explaining why the existing answer is bad so that readers can judge for themselves. Both of those are fine - putting your opinion in someone else's post (when they disagree with you) is *not* fine.

Comment: What you can do is *advise* to improve/correct the post. Editing an incorrect post in order to make it right is not the way to go. You can downvote if the answer isn't right or vague. Look to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36022122/2412895) where i advised the author to add a link to clarify a statement in his answer. He allowed me to edit his post (which I did). It's a different case, true, but still, it depends of the approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attempted to edit and it was rejected, your remaining options are basically to downvote his answer and provide an answer yourself. If others agree that his answer is wrong they will also downvote and hopefully a better quality answer will emerge as the front runner.

However, I'm afraid that's not likely to happen in this instance - I think Alexey is right.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't want to pollute with the same answer.  But you've explained it from a different perspective and actually it makes sense to add my own answer and be more clear.